# Columns are being created in SharePoint but only some of them will populate

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, sharepoint-library

So I have an InfoPath form with several fields and a group in it. All of them are promoted to columns in SharePoint, and the SharePoint site reflects that (the columns all appear). The issue I'm running into is that the fields are populating the columns, but the group is not. The group is a multiple-selection list box.

Does anyone know why the group might be posing an issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you publish the InfoPath form to a list or Form library?

If publish to a Form library, we can select the fieldname under the group name and select “merge” as function as below:

[image]